# Find when the value changes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to return values when it changes from one to another.

In the below example, I want to return studentname,examnum, and grade when his/her grade goes down(from A to C) order by ExamNum(4 is the most recent exam). The rows to be returned are highlighted in Return column(the table doesn't have return column).

For example, I want to show Tom,4,B because he had A in examnum=3 but on his next exam he's go B (examnum=4).

I have no idea where to even begin..

SELECT Student,ExamNum,Grade, RowNum= ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (PARTITION BY StudentORDER BY ExamNum)
  FROM dbo.Exam

```
    Student  ExamNum  Grade   Return
Tom              1      B
Tom              2      A
Tom              3      A
Tom              4      B       *
Angela           1      B
Angela           2      B
Angela           3      A
Angela           4      B       *
Shawn            1      A
Shawn            2      C       *
Shawn            3      A
Shawn            4      A
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             lag(e.grade) over (partition by e.student order by e.examNum) as prev_grade
      from exam e
     ) e
where e.grade < e.prev_grade;
```

Comment: Thank you but the grade isn't numeric.

Comment: @inincubus . . . And your point is?  Comparison work find on strings as well.

Comment: I see your points. the actual data isn't really alphabetical values but I can create a temp table and put them in order.

Answer (score 1):

You can also call external code based on a trigger if you are interested to intercept the moment when the grade has actualy changed.

For oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdev/calling-Java-from-database-triggers.html#GUID-5C498DEF-0348-484D-AA26-2A88EF348D5C

For Ms SQL server : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/java/howto-call-java-from-sql?view=sqlallproducts-allversions

You have two main aproaches. You can do Polling or you can Push the change.